# Customize BeanFactory with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?

Tags: java, spring

The [slow autowire by type problem](http://jawspeak.com/2010/11/28/spring-slow-autowiring-by-type-getbeannamesfortype-fix-10x-speed-boost-3600ms-to/) has finally been solved by creating a caching bean factory.

I would really like to be able to use such a CachingByTypeBeanFactory together with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner for running JUnit tests with @Autowired. But it does not seem to be possible to change the Bean Factory on the application context via the ContextLoader.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your own ContextLoader and attach this annotation to your JUnit class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=YourLoader.class)
```

This is my example Loader which instantiates another or custom ApplicationContext which in turn may be initialized with custom BeanFactory (depending of capabilities):

```
public class XmlWebApplicationContextLoader extends AbstractContextLoader {

    public final ConfigurableApplicationContext loadContext(final String... locations) throws Exception {
        ServletContext servletContext = new MockServletContext("war", new FileSystemResourceLoader());
        GenericWebApplicationContext webContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webContext);
        webContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(webContext).loadBeanDefinitions(locations);        
        AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(webContext);
        webContext.refresh();
        webContext.registerShutdownHook();
        return webContext;
    }

    protected String getResourceSuffix() {
        return "";
    }
```

}

In above case application context (provided by Spring Framework) has constructor:

```
public GenericWebApplicationContext(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    super(beanFactory);
}
```

Comment: And exactly how does this help? I've been reading the spring source code of ContextLoader and I can't seem to make it accept my BeanFactory. And AFIK ContextLoader != BeanFactory

Comment: What application context type you are using? You can instantiate GenericApplicationContext with new BF and then return it with loadContext method of your custom loader.

Comment: Looks right to me.  The ContextLoader is the interface which specifies how to turn an array of strings into an application context.